# Is there a CSS3 selector driven Document Object Model (DOM) API for Delphi?

Tags: html, css, delphi, xhtml

Or something that allows you to parse HTML in a similar way to JQuery?

If not, in your opinion what is the best way to parse though HTML without having to be a regular expression expert and not rely on Internet Explorer to parse information for you? (AKA, not rely on something like: IEParser by bsalsa.com)

Thanks

-Brad

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [diHtmlParser](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/htmlparser/index) which I believe will give you what your after.

Comment: Not that would work without external requirements, or building a parser yourself.

Comment: I've used DIHtmlParser quite a bit. Although it's pretty good, it does require a bit of getting used to. When it comes to parsing HTML, it really depends on exactly what you need to parse out of the HTML. If you're just looking for certain information, it's easier than if you need to parse all of the HTML (as in building a DOM). What I'm still looking for is one that can parse the HTML and give me a reference to WHERE the html tag/entity is in the original source. (Think HTML Editor)

Answer (score 3):

There is a Delphi DOM HTML parser and converter available at SourceForge, so it is Open Source and free.

You can find it at: http://htmlp.sourceforge.net/

and the project page at SourceForge is: http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlp/

Comment: project is too old as I see :(

Comment: It's from 2003 but it's not too old if it works. How old is JQuery? And being "old" means it will work for versions of Delphi pre-Delphi 2009. You get all the source so you can make any customizations or updates yourself. And, if you plan to really use it, you can bring it up-to-date and post a new version for others.

Comment: Your only other possibility that I see is to interface with some other API, e.g. the Apache Xerces Project http://xerces.apache.org/ - but I have no idea how you'd do it.

Comment: I just found HTMLP the other day, and after spending much time playing with it and modifying it for a specific need I found that it has a couple of problems. 1. It doesn't parse the DOCTYPE. 2. It doesn't parse SCRIPT sections correctly, making it's formatter (output) corrupt the script code. 3. It doesn't handle broken html very well.